# How to use babel-polyfill in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In Babel [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) they just say that to include `import "babel-polyfill";` so that I can use ES6 generators but after I included that line in my gulpfile.js I still gen an exception : `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`
This is my gulpfile.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

var gulp = require("gulp"),
babel = require("gulp-babel"),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task("babel", function() {
return gulp.src(jsSrc)
    .pipe(concat('Main.js'))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
    .pipe(rename('Main-min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

`jsSrc` have `maines6.js` and other `.js` files. In `maines6.js` here is my generator:

```
function* anotherGenerator(i) {
  yield i + 1;
  yield i + 2;
  yield i + 3;
}
```

I don't know how to use this.. can you help me?

Comment: You need to import it into your actual Main.js since that's where it's being used.

Comment: Yeah generator is supported by Chrome. But I don't want to seperate the generator into other file.

Comment: Just follow **Usage in Browser** section in the same Babel [docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#usage-in-browser) you referred in your question.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Since you're just using gulp and not some sort of module bundler(webpack for e.g)</strike>

You should follow this guide https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel#runtime

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

and then use it like this

```
.pipe(babel({
        plugins: ['transform-runtime']
    }))
```

Should do the trick :)

**EDIT:**

Seems that babel-plugin-transform-runtime add require calls to the transformed file, so I guess you'll need to use a module loader. I would suggest webpack, although there are alternative like browserify and jspm.

You'll need

```
npm install -g webpack
npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-polyfill babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Then you'll need to create a webpack.config.js file. Here's a very primitive setup.

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './entries/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

With the config above the file structure should looke like this

```
project/
    node_modules/
    app/
        entries/
            main.js
    dist/
        main.js
    webpack.config.js
    package.json
```

Then just run `webpack` from your command line. If you want to get the minified version run `webpack -p`

Comment: It solve the `generation` exception but now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.
Here is the line that cause the proble from chrome devtools console:
`var _regenerator = require("babel-runtime/regenerator");`

Comment: Well this sucks :( Babel seems to include requires in the transformer code, so it seems that you'll need to use some kind of a module bundler. I would suggest webpack.

Comment: Yes, I'll be checking it out, thanks.. 
Anyway should I close my question or not?
I thought that `babel-polyfill` is meant to be used with gulp but it's not..

Comment: Yeah, you can close it :)

Answer (score 1):

> to include the polyfill you need to require it at the top of the entry point to your application.

`import 'babel/polyfill'` would need to go at the top of your jsSrc entry file

Comment: I place import at the top and I think babel transform it to  `require("babel/polyfill");.`
Then I got
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: In order to use the polyfill with `require` or `import` you must set up a module loader. Two popular choices are `webpack` and `browserify`. Check out the __Usage in Browser__ section: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. The __Usage in Browser__ section is only if you want to forgo a module loader (AKA bundler) in your build process.

Comment: So.. the polyfill doesn't meant to be used with gulp-babel right?

Comment: Correct. It is meant to be used inside of your actual codebase. There are different methods if you are trying to use ES2015 in your gulpfile, though. However, if you follow a webpack + babel6 tutorial I think you will find what you are looking for. You can then include the [regenerator transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/) to use generator functions.

Comment: Here is one such tutorial: http://jamesknelson.com/using-es6-in-the-browser-with-babel-6-and-webpack/. It even includes the `babel-polyfill`.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll be cheking it out.. Maybe combining Webpack and gulp will make my development easier

Comment: You may also find you don't need gulp at all. Webpack is very powerful.

Comment: Welcome to the chaos. Enjoy!